# Cache file content and then extract matches using regex

Tags: arrays, regex, bash

Please forgive a bash newbie for any silly questions.

I am really stuck here and I would love to know how this works and what I am doing wrong.

I have written this script which is supposed to capture syslog server based on protocol.

The input is as follows:

```
sys syslog {
    include "destination remote_server {tcp(\"10.1.0.100\" port (514));tcp(\"192.168.1.5\" port (514));udp(\"192.168.1.60\" port (514));};filter f_alllogs {level (debug...emerg);};log {source(local);filter(f_alllogs);destination(remote_server);};"
    remote-servers {
        mysyslog {
            host 192.168.1.1
        }
        remotesyslog1 {
            host 192.168.1.2
        }
        remotesyslog2 {
            host 192.168.1.3
            local-ip 10.0.0.50
        }
    }
}
```

From this I would like to get something like in the end:

```
tcp=10.1.0.100
tcp=192.168.1.50
udp=192.168.1.60
udp=192.168.1.1
udp=192.168.1.2
udp=192.168.1.3
```

So I started with a bash script to parse the output.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Save output to file
syslogoutput=$(< /home/patrik/input)

echo "Testing variable:"
echo $syslogoutput
echo ""
#Declare array
tcpservers=()

echo $syslogoutput | while read line ; do

        matches=($(echo $line | grep -Po '(tcp\("[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}")'))

        #If number of matches is greater than 0, save them to tcpservers
        if [ ${#matches[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
                tcpservers=("${matches[@]}")

                #Echoing matches
                echo "Testing matches in loop:"
                for i in "${matches[@]}"; do
                    echo $i
                done
        fi
done

echo "Testing output:"
for i in "${tcpservers[@]}"; do
        echo $i
done
```

I expected something like this:

```
...input file separated by line breaks
Testing matches in loop:
tcp("10.1.0.100"
tcp("192.168.1.5"
Testing output:
tcp("10.1.0.100"
tcp("192.168.1.5"
```

But instead I get:

```
sys syslog { include "destination remote_server {tcp(\"10.1.0.100\" port (514));tcp(\"192.168.1.5\" port (514));udp(\"192.168.1.60\" port (514));};filter f_alllogs {level (debug...emerg);};log {source(local);filter(f_alllogs);destination(remote_server);};" remote-servers { mysyslog { host 192.168.1.1 } remotesyslog1 { host 192.168.1.2 } remotesyslog2 { host 192.168.1.3 local-ip 10.0.0.50 } } }

Testing matches in loop:
tcp("10.1.0.100"
tcp("192.168.1.5"
Testing output:
```

So on to my questions:

1. Why isn't `tcpservers=("${matches[@]}")` working?
2. Why isn't the output cached with line breaks?
3. Why does bash scripting make me want to jump from a tall building every time I try it?

/Patrik

Comment: Use a real language for harder tasks. Perl/Python/Ruby are more suitable than shell for this kind of work.

Comment: I would if I could. Sadly I'm restricted to bash for this.

Comment: Also, setting a variable in a subshell (i.e. after the `|`) doesn't change its value in the parent.

Comment: @PatrikJ: How do you even construct the o/p you need from the syslog? `10.0.0.50` is not even present with tcp/udp word before

Comment: Actually it's not supposed to be. Only lines that begins with host <ip> will be put in the udp list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use redirection, as it starts the loop in a subshell, and variables form a subshell don't propagate into the parent shell.

```
while read line ; do
    # ...
done <<< "$syslogoutput"
```

You also overwrite the tcpservers on each iteration. Change the assignment to

```
tcpservers+=("${matches[@]}")
#         ^
#         |
#  add to an array, don't overwrite
```

Comment: Sweet, that works! May I ask why it's being overwritten? I thought `tcpservers=("${matches[@]}")` meant that it copies matches to tcpservers?

Comment: @PatrikJ: Yes, but it overwrites the values that were stored in tcpservers before. It might be a non-issue if matches are populated just once.

Comment: It's not. There's only one line. But your way is prettier. Thank you for your help!